# Wrong SVG width Inside another SVG

Tags: html, firefox, svg, inline-svg

In Firefox 53.0.3 i've noticed a strange behavior putting one SVG with the "viewBox" attribute inside another one.

Take as example this code or [this pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yXNRQj?editors=1100).

```
<svg id="svgroot" height="812" width="1620">

  <svg id="svgcontent" width="696" height="480" x="392" y="117" viewBox="0 0 580 400">
    <g style="pointer-events:none">
      <title style="pointer-events:inherit">background</title>
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" id="canvas_background_fill" fill="red" style="pointer-events:inherit"></rect>
    </g>
  </svg>

</svg>
```

As we can see we have #svgcontent with a with of 696 and height of 480, but if you inspect the element the width is 835 and the height 576.

In chrome this example works as expected.

Is this a firefox bug or i'm doing something wrong?

**Edit:** I've noticed another thing. The content's width and height of the child SVG are the same of attributes values.

Seems that the wrong dimension value came from:

```
// 696 * ( 696 / 580 )
// 696 * 1.2
// 835
currentWidth = attributeWidth * ( attributeWidth / viewboxWidth );
```

Comment: May I add to the confusion? 1. If you raise the size of the rectangle, you will find that it is clipped not at the size given by the Inspector, but at the correct 696 ✕ 480. 2. `document.querySelector('#svgcontent').getCTM()` in FF gives you the identity transform, while Chrome returns (1.2, 0, 0, 1.2, 392,117).

Comment: I guess the inspector is buggy, no?